# Plotting a "Column" chart type in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame (the .csv file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14322966/plotData.csv)):

> monthlyData   InmonthlyDataOut    monthlyDataInOut    monthlyDataOutOut
>
> 365.506166    404.953832  233.2757866667  277.0273782857
>
> 83.6223894415 304.9411340597  83.3290775473   177.251202913
>
> 215.805346    261.719192  200.0503536078  266.8439798431
>
> 56.2463860296 231.5178528013  49.3354487884   214.3130820265
>
> 141.0012916923    198.2611403077  145.39269568    151.4908766939
>
> 872.4538060177    865.5696917647  938.4100522767  941.1982855211
>
> 243.5898831429    46.6781673766   219.9683379423  41.7586427475
>
> 41.2589185368 309.2830683077  34.0903168571   319.34763075
>
> 74.2917333    287.1698030361  88.9124322553   285.4422067097
>
> 66.4870296599 NA          63.1332482097   224.7596242353
>
> NA            NA          40.0992221975   NA

In LibreOffice I can easily plot a chart of type "Column". The screenshot is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14322966/chart.png).

I have been trying to get the same (similar) plot in R using barplot().

```
plot4 <- barplot(as.matrix(plotData),)
```

No success so far.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

EDIT: I think I have found the answer.

```
plotData <- do.call(rbind, plotData)
plotThroughput <- barplot(plotData,
                          main="Average Throughput",
                          xlab="Nodes",
                          beside=TRUE,
                          ylab="Throughput (Mbps)",
)
```

Comment: `barplot` and `barchart` are completely different plots in different packages.  Please update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for spotting it. Fixed my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

id <- factor(1:nrow(DF))
long <- melt(transform(DF, id = id), id = "id") # add id col; melt to long form
ggplot(long, aes(id, value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

*REVISED*  Minor code improvements.

Comment: I was one minute behind... Hey, want to pair code sometime?

Comment: This is what I needed. Looks much better than my answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I used the libraries `reshape` and `ggplot` and the `discretize` function in the `arules` package.

```
#Example data
plotData <- data.frame(structure(replicate(4, runif(50, 50, 200), simplify = FALSE), .Names = cs))
plotData2 <- melt(plotData)
plotData2$value <- arules::discretize(plotData2$value, categories = 5)
ggplot(plotData2, aes(x = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge', binwidth = 30, width = 0.9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of `ggplot` is that you can easily do things like this, which IMO is *much* clearer.

[image]

```
library(ggplt2)
library(reshape2)
df <- read.csv("plotdata.csv")
gg <- melt(cbind(id=factor(1:nrow(df)),df),id="id")
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=id,y=value,fill=variable),stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

[image]

```
gg <- melt(cbind(id=factor(1:nrow(df)),df),id="id")
gg <- cbind(facet=rep(1:2,each=2*nrow(df)),gg)
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=id,y=value,fill=variable),stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  facet_grid(facet~.)+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Comment: Thank you jlhoward. Do I need to run the `ggplot(gg) + ...` command in R console only? I ran it in my script but got no results.

Comment: Put the whole thing in a call to `plot(...)`, or (more commonly), write `ggp <- ggplot(gg)+...+...` and then `plot(ggp)`. In the R console, the RHS of an expression is automatically printed, This is suppressed in scripts and function calls (and also loops!), so you have to print it explicitly. In this case, either print or plot would work.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you. Also, I like the way you represented my data. It is much easier to see the general picture.
Just one question here: is it possible to have monthlyDataIn and monthlyDataOut plotted together and monthlyDataInOut and monthlyDatOutOut together?